# Select values of a row into separate variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server. The problem is how can I save the values of each column of a single row into separate variable in SQL Server 2012.

Something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, School 
FROM tblSchool 
WHERE Id = 2
```

Then save the values of Id, Name, School into separate variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the values to be stored in separate variables (Your query returns only one matching row)
You can do like following

```
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @School VARCHAR(100)
SELECT TOP 1 @ID=Id,@Name=Name,@School=School FROM tblSchool WHERE Id=2
```

SQL Server also supports table type variables, for your case you can create a table type as following.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyVairable] AS TABLE(
    Id                    INT NOT NULL,
    Name                   VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    School                 VARCHAR(100)
 )
```

Declare the variable as following.

```
 DECLARE @MyVariable [dbo].[MyVairable]
```

To select the rows into your variable.

```
INSERT INTO @MyVariable
SELECT Id,Name,School FROM tblSchool WHERE Id=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply Declare the variables and stored it using:

```
DECLARE @ID INT, @Name VARCHAR(50), @School VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @ID=Id,@Name=Name,@School=School FROM tblSchool WHERE Id=2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @ID INT 
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @School VARCHAR(50)

SELECT @ID=Id,@Name=Name,@School=School 
FROM tblSchool 
WHERE Id=2
```